# Regex and Python - Clean Up UTF8 Text File

Tags: python, regex

New to Python.  Using 2.7.3.  Class assignment for a mandatory programming class for a legal assistat degree.

I'd like to read UTF8 Text File of draft court statements and clean up as follows.

Read input text file line by line

In each line,
(1) capitalize first letters of sentence (including first character of the line)
(2) make certain that all commas, periods, and semi-colons are followed by a space character

Write output text file line by line

This is what I have so far based on reading other stackoverflow posts.  It's not working well.  Please help.  Thank you.

```
import codecs
import sys
import os
import re

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')


with codecs.open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
    filedata = file.read().replace(' \r\n', '\r\n')

re.sub(r'(?<=[.,;])(?=[^\s])', r' ', filedata)

rtn = re.split('([.!?] *)', filedata)
filedata = ''.join([i.capitalize() for i in rtn])
filedata = filedata[0].upper() + filedata[1:] 


with codecs.open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(filedata)
```

Example text file

```
instead of arguing,ask her, "what can i do?"forgo postponing the problem. instead, talk to her.that single gesture will promote peace.
```

Desired output:

```
Instead of arguing, ask her, "What can I do?"  Forgo postponing the problem.  Instead, talk to her.  That single gesture will promote peace.
```

Comment: As you’re new to Python you should be using Python 3.x preferably the most recent. Python 3 completely changes handling of unicode, very much for the better compared to Python 2.x. Python 2.x is effectively obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
import re

filedata = 'instead of arguing,ask her, "what can i do?"forgo postponing the problem. instead, talk to her.that single gesture will promote peace.'

print(filedata)

# add space, match .,; but not followed by space \s
filedata = re.sub(r'([,\.;"])((?!\s).)', r'\1 \2', filedata)

# clean space in quotation: " What can i do?"
filedata = re.sub(r'"\s([^"]+")', r'"\1', filedata)

# make uppercase first letter of sentence or after dot and quote
filedata = re.sub(r'(^.|\.\s\w|"\s?\w)', lambda m: m.group(1).upper(), filedata)

print(filedata)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a single pattern and check for existence of the capture groups to do the different replacements.

```
("[^"]*"|\.|^)\s*(\S)|([,;])(?=\S)
```

*Explanation*

- `("[^"]*"|\.|^)` Capture **group 1**, match either from `"..."` or a dot or assert the start of the string
- `\s*(\S)` Match 0+ whitespace chars and capture a non whitespace char in **group 2**
- `|` Or
- `([,;])(?=\S)` Capture in **group 3** either `,` or `;` asserting a non whitespace char at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2VWgY5/1)

```
import re

regex = r"""("[^"]*"|\.|^)\s*(\S)|([,;])(?=\S)"""
s = "instead of arguing,ask her, \"what can i do?\"forgo postponing the problem. instead, talk to her.that single gesture will promote peace."
result = re.sub(regex, lambda m: m.group(3) + " " if m.group(3) else (m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2).upper()), s)
print(result)
```

Output

```
Instead of arguing, ask her, "what can i do?" Forgo postponing the problem. Instead, talk to her. That single gesture will promote peace.
```

Note that `\S` or `[^\s]` matches non whitespace characters.